# PostgreSQL does not use the gist index (btree_gist) when using the distance operator

Tags: postgresql, indexing, distance, gist, btree-gist

When I use the distance operator with a gist index, potgres still performs a sequential scan.

```
create extension btree_gist;

create table telemetry1(
    time timestamptz primary KEY,
    value DOUBLE PRECISION
);



create index telemetry1_idx on telemetry1 using gist(time);

insert into telemetry1
select t.time, random()
from generate_series(timestamptz '2021-07-24 00:00:00.000000',
                     timestamptz '2021-07-25 23:59:59.000000',
                     interval '250 milliseconds') as t(time);

analyze telemetry1;
                 
explain
select * 
from telemetry1 as t
where t.time <-> timestamptz '2021-07-25' = interval '1 year';
```

```
Gather  (cost=1000.00..13603.38 rows=5184 width=16)
  Workers Planned: 2
  ->  Parallel Seq Scan on telemetry1 t  (cost=0.00..12084.98 rows=2160 width=16)
        Filter: (("time" <-> '2021-07-25 00:00:00-03'::timestamp with time zone) = '1 year'::interval)
```

Comment: Why not use a B-Tree index to begin with? Probably more efficient than a GiST index anyway

Comment: btree does not support distance operator (<->)

Comment: I know, but you can just rewrite the condition using `>=` and `<`. Btw: your sample query won't return anything to begin with because there is no row in your sample data where the distance is _exactly_ 1 year

Comment: Yes, I put the data example wrong. My idea was to use the distance operator to test the use of the index with btree_gist, but I can rewrite it using >= and <=.

Comment: The KNN mechanism for use with ORDER BY a distance (with a LIMIT) not for testing a distance for equality.

Comment: Ok, thank you very much! I didn't understand that it was only for sorting!